# avoid repeating condition in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query to be executed on postgresql

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_client) FROM contract c
INNER JOIN bundle b ON c.bundle_id = b.id
INNER JOIN payment_method pm ON pm.id = c.payment_method_id
WHERE country_id=1 AND b.platform_id=1  AND pm.name <> 'RIB'
  AND CONDITION_1
  AND id_client NOT IN (
    SELECT id_client FROM contract c1
    INNER JOIN bundle b1 ON (c1.bundle_id = b1.id)
    INNER JOIN payment_method pm1 ON pm1.id = c1.payment_method_id
    WHERE c1.country_id=1 AND b1.platform_id=1 AND pm1.name <> 'RIB'
      AND CONDITION_2);
```

I don't like it because it's the same query repeated twice except of CONDITION_1 and CONDITION_2 (and I have another example where it's repeated 3 times).

It's also very slow as well.

I tried to rewrite it as the following:

```
WITH
filter_cpm AS (
    SELECT * FROM contract c
    INNER JOIN bundle b ON b.id = c.bundle_id
    INNER JOIN payment_method pm ON pm.id = c.payment_method_id
      WHERE c.country_id = 1 AND b.platform_id = 1 AND pm.name <> 'RIB'
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_client) FROM filter_cpm
    WHERE CONDITION_1
      AND id_client NOT IN (
        SELECT id_client FROM filter_cpm
        WHERE CONDITION_2);
```

Now it's DRY but it's two times slower.

How can I re-write the query to have the same (or better) performance?

EDIT: I cannot join two conditions with AND. For example if CONDITION_1 and CONDITION_2 are VIP, then I want to select clients who were re-qualified from NOT VIP to VIP.

Answer (score 1):

You can select from the common table expression twice, using an outer join:

```
WITH filter_cpm AS (SELECT *
                      FROM CONTRACT c
                      INNER JOIN BUNDLE b
                        ON b.ID = c.BUNDLE_ID
                      INNER JOIN PAYMENT_METHOD pm
                        ON pm.ID = c.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID
                      WHERE c.COUNTRY_ID = 1 AND
                            b.PLATFORM_ID = 1 AND
                            pm.NAME <> 'RIB')
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fc1.ID_CLIENT)
  FROM filter_cpm fc1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN filter_cpm fc2
    ON fc2.ID_CLIENT = fc1.ID_CLIENT AND
       CONDITION_2
  WHERE fc1.CONDITION_1 AND
        fc2.ID_CLIENT IS NULL
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, your query gives the same result as two my queries. And it takes 3 min, the same as my second query. The first one is executed in 1min30

Comment: You might consider limiting FILTER_CPM to only pull back the fields you actually need. From what I can see the only field which is actually used is ID_CLIENT, but of course I have no idea what CONDITION_1 and CONDITION_2 might be. Then create full indexes on CONTRACT, BUNDLE, and PAYMENT_METHOD for all the fields involved and see if you can turn FULL TABLE SCANs into INDEX SCANs.